# `curl_easy_send` and `curl_easy_recv` over SSL: how to handle `CURLE_AGAIN`?

Tags: c++, ssl, libcurl

`curl_easy_send` and `curl_easy_recv` return `CURLE_AGAIN` when they can not send data immediatelly due to slow network connection.

It is possible to get socket wrapped by `libcurl` and call `poll` or `select` on that socket; if we call `curl_easy_send`, we'll wait until we can write more data (i. e. we'll use `POLLOUT` with `poll`), and for `curl_easy_recv` we'll wait until incoming data is available (i. e. we'll use `POLLIN` with `poll`).

This approach will not work for SSL connection, because even when we read SSL data, OpenSSL may need to write (for example, to perform new handshake). So, even we use `curl_easy_send`, we have no idea whether we have to use `POLLIN` or `POLLOUT`.

OpenSSL has `SSL_want` function for that issue. However, we need pointer to SSL session if we want to call `SSL_want`.

I tried to use `CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR` to get OpenSSL session pointer; this method returns `null` always however when we use `CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY`.

**So, how to handle `CURLE_AGAIN` in a correct way with `curl_easy_send` and `curl_easy_recv` over SSL?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself finally. I don't understand for what reason `libcurl` team implemented `CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR` in such a way that it returns `nullptr` even connection is made over SSL and Curl object still contains the SSL session pointer, but can not return it in a correct way. I can only hope that they will fix this issue in future versions and `libcurl` users will not have to invent bicycle.

Fortunatelly, we can get SSL session (at least for `OpenSSL`) in following way:

1. Use `CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION` to be able to get SSL context when Curl will create it.
2. Use `SSL_CTX_set_info_callback` with this context to be able to intercept new SSL session creation event.
3. Use this SSL session with `SSL_want` function to handle `CURLE_AGAIN` in a correct way.